# How to center an image on another image in HTML

Tags: html, css

```
<tr>
    <td style='text-align: center;'>    
        <img style='height: 50px;width:50px;' src='./images/01.png' >       
        <img style='height: 15px;width:15px;'src='./images/02.png' >    
    </td> 
</tr>
```

How can I position  the 02.png   to the center  of the 01.png? For 1 layer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18556157/how-to-center-one-image-over-another
You can find your answer here.

Answer (score -1):

You can use position relative in parent (td element) and position absolute in image 2 style.

```css
#col {
  position: relative;
}

#img-1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#img-2 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 16px;
  top: 14px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="col">
      <img id="img-1" src="img-1.jpg">
      <img id="img-2" src="img-2.jpg">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```